# Mockito - Mocking Silhouette always throws NullPointerException

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, specs2, silhouette

I'm using play framework 2.5 and silhouette library with scala 2.11.
And writing test code using play specs2 and mockito.
Now, I've been trying mock to throw an exception.
But, the mock always throws NullPointerException before it's called.

Here's the target of test code.

```
class TestController @Inject() (
  ...
  silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv]) extends Controller {

  def target() = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    try {
      silhouette.env.authenticatorService.discard(request.authenticator, Ok)
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>
        Future.successful(InternalServerError(...))
    }
  }
}
```

Test code as below.

```
class TestControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  ...
  trait Context extends Scope {
    val mockTest = mock[Silhouette[DefaultEnv]]

    // This always throws a NullPointerException.
    mockTest.env.authenticatorService.discard(any[JWTAuthenticator], any[Result])(any[RequestHeader]) throws new AuthenticatorDiscardingException("AuthenticatorDiscardingException")

    lazy val appMock = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .overrides(new FakeModule)
      .overrides(bind[Silhouette[DefaultEnv]].toInstance(mockTest))
      .build
  }
  ...
}
```

I've got error messages as following.

```
[error]      java.lang.NullPointerException: null (TestControllerSpec.scala:123)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$Context$1$$anonfun$40.apply(TestControllerSpec.scala:123)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$Context$1$$anonfun$40.apply(TestControllerSpec.scala:123)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$Context$1$class.$init$(TestControllerSpec.scala:123)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$18$$anon$32.<init>(TestControllerSpec.scala:393)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(TestControllerSpec.scala:393)
[error] controllers.TestControllerSpec$$anonfun$29$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(TestControllerSpec.scala:393)
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue? I am facing the issue as well.

Comment: No, I couldn't resolved this issue at last. hope to be resolved this in latest version.